# Display annotation of length of a plotted line when hovered over

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Using [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com) I'll be plotting a series that looks like a staircase: consecutive horizontal and vertical lines. (With varying width and constant height).

I would like to have an annotation or label show the length of a horizontal line when it is hovered over. How might this be done? Perhaps there is a way of:

- providing a callback that gets called when a line segment is hovered over
- use that callback to add a temporary annotation (with the documented annotations feature)

Or perhaps there's a better way?

Example:

```
<head><script  
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graphdiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    [
        [0, 1],     // Starts at height 1, step width is 2
        [2, 2],     // step width is 1
        [3, 3],     // step width is 0.5
        [3.5, 4],   // step width is 0.25
        [3.75, 5],  // remainder is at height 5
    ],
    {
        stepPlot: true
    });
</script>
</body>
```

[See here for further examples of step plots](http://dygraphs.com/tests/steps.html) on the Dygraphs site

**Progress:**

I am focusing around a method I found in [the source code of dygraph.js](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/src/dygraph.js): `findClosestPoint()`. Unfortunately it does a linear (brute force) search of points, on the visible canvas (I think), but it'll do. So I need to work out:

1. What calls it,
2. Which of those callers are what I should tap into
3. How to attach a callback to it

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: @JonasGrumann, I've added some sample code - couldn't get it working on jsfiddle, I'm guessing because it needs https?

Comment: You can use the js from cdnjs.com. Link are on dygraphs downloadpage or you can check the fiddles in my answer post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use annotate to solve this decently I think (http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html)

Here is a jsfiddle with possible solution: [Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xbj847x/1/)

Basically you add anotations like this:

```
g.setAnnotations([
    {      
      series: "seriesX",
      x: 0,
      shortText: "2"
    },
    ...
```

that would set a 2 at the start of the first line..
then you can have a 1 for the length of the seconf line with another anotation there and so on:

```
...
{      
   series: "seriesX",
   x: 2,
   shortText: "1"
}
...
```

I understand that this is not when you hover the line but this is as close as you get using dygraphs I think. Other option is to listen to mousemove and use a div above the graph to position correctly based on mouse coords/graph coords but that is a lot more code.

**Edit:**
Ok, I understand if there are many points tight together that would look horrible.
You can show and hide the annotation on hover like this: [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xbj847x/2/)

I used jQuery to select the annotation also changed the text a bit to select it more easily if many points have same title. You can prob do the selection manually in other ways if you don't use jQuery.

```
      g.updateOptions( {
        annotationMouseOverHandler: function(annotation, point, dygraph, event)
        {       
        var anno = $(".dygraphDefaultAnnotation[title='" + annotation.text +"']");
            //alert(annotation.text);
            anno.removeClass("annotationHidden");
        },
      annotationMouseOutHandler:function(annotation, point, dygraph, event)
        {
        var anno = $(".dygraphDefaultAnnotation[title='" + annotation.text +"']");
            //alert(annotation.text);
            anno.addClass("annotationHidden");
        }
        });
```

And also create the annotation array using a loop so it is not too much code.

Comment: Thanks... I was thinking the same as your first suggestion. The problem is that the graph will be enormous, hence why I chose Dygraphs, as it gives zooming and panning out of the box. All the annotations would create a jumble, and possibly hit performance. I might try rooting around the source code to look for a possible hack. It already finds the closest series and points, so it must surely be easy once you know how!

Comment: @Jodes Edited with a possible way to handle the mouse events to make it less cluttered if many points. you can also adjust how the annotation looks with  an extra class thats allways on the annotation using the cssClass property of an annotation.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! Have you considered contributing to Dygraphs  documentation? It needs 4 more people with an up vote on the tag to enable contributions. It's not a well known library, but very useful! The out-of-the-box zoom and panning is something I haven't seen on any other library